# How to make subcomponent singleton in dagger 2?

Tags: android, dagger-2

I want to make my subcomponent to be a singleton so that I can have Login Presenter to be a singleton as well. Is this possible?

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = AppModule.class)
public interface AppComponent {
    LoginComponent getLoginComponent();
}

@Singleton
@Subcomponent(modules = LoginModule.class)
public interface LoginComponent {
}

public class LoginComponent {
    @Singleton
    LoginPresenter getLoginPresenter();
}
```

Comment: So make your `LoginPresenter` a singleton. Why do you have to provide it from your SubComponent?

Comment: For me subcomponent represents a feature and I want to keep all my object creation there.

Comment: Components and subcomponents are objects meant to encapsulate the binding graph.  The instances created by those bindings may optionally have lifecycles which match that of the component and are associated with a logical concept defined by the scope annotation.  So, you should be using components and subcomponents to model related lifecycles (e.g. Application/Singleton, Activity, etc. in Android or Singleton, Request in a server), not features.

Feature-level composition should be done with modules as you seem to have already done.

Comment: If I use module for feature level composition then my AppComponent would get larger and larger and I want to avoid this for organization sake. But I guess you are right that two different components cannot have the same life cycle. I was hoping this would be possible.

Answer (score 4):

`@Subcomponent`s cannot be made `@Singleton`.

While the `@Singleton` spec is a little vague about it, "singleton" canonically means "one per application".  Since a `@Subcomponent` is created via a factory method on a component, the *only* way in which your singleton-bound instances would be "one per application" would be if the singleton subcomponent were a child of a singleton component and its factory method were *only ever invoked once* per application.  Enforcing that constraint is virtually impossible, so the pattern would just be a likely source of bugs.

Comment: Do you know if this "limitation" changed recently? It seems I'm able to do it now, but I'm not sure if it's a bug (or if I'm doing something wrong), since I couldn't find proper release notes.

Comment: If you can do it, it's a bug.  Can you file it?

Comment: Even when there are multiple `@Subcomponent` instances, the singleton instances that are defined in the main `@Singleton` component modules are still singleton even when they are requested in different subcomponent instances. Is my assumption correct?