# Dagger 2: DaggerBroadcastReceiver recreates Subcomponent

Tags: android, dependency-injection, broadcastreceiver, dagger

Assume I want to have a single, application-wide instance of `SomeSingletonClass`. I created a Dagger module which provides such object:

```
@Module
public interface MyModule {

    @Provider
    @Singleton
    SomeSingletonClass provideSomeSingletonClass() {
       return new SomeSingletonClass();
    }
```

I also want to use BroadcastReciever:

```
public class MyReceiver extends DaggerBroadcastReceiver {

    @Inject
    SomeSingletonClass someSingletonClass;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
        ...
    }
}
```

It has its own module:

```
@Module
public abstract class MyReceiverModule {
    @Singleton
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = {MyModule.class})
    abstract MyReceiver myReceiver();
}
```

Now, each call to `onReceive()` causes a call to `super.onReceive()` which in turn calls `AndroidInjection.inject(this, context)`. This causes to recreate subcomponent of `MyReceiver` and associated dependencies, including `SomeSingletonClass`.

What is the proper way to preserve singleton instances when using DaggerBroadcastReceiver?

Comment: `@Singleton` is just a default `@Scope` annotation that comes with the Dagger library.  `@Scope` only has a requirement that scoped component/subcomponent match the scoped dependencies - meaning they are "scoped" the same (which is what you have - your "scoped" objects last as long as the subcomonent of the same scope).  If you require a single instance you need to scope it to the root parent Component, typically created in the `Application` class in Android.  If you require a custom `@Scope` just create one, reserve the `@Singleton` for your root Component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem in my case was that I added `@Singleton` to subcomponent created by `@ContributesAndroidInjector`. As pointed out in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37800129/3401555) by gk5885 to similar question:

> @Subcomponents cannot be made @Singleton.

The reason is that, since subcomponent may be recreated by component, the @Singleton instance will be kept the same for the subcomponent instance only. The solution was to remove `@Singleton` annotation from subcomponents and the move module providing singleton to the root component, which was then marked as a `@Singleton`.